# Java 9 Runtime Exception calling org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig

Tags: java, jersey, java-9, invocationtargetexception

My app works great with java 1.8 (and earlier), however when I rebuilt the application to use java 9, I receive the following stack trace. The reason for the update is because I need to use the new `ProcessHandle.current()`, which does not exist in earlier versions.

```
c:\>java -jar ./build/bin/DataMover.jar
DataMover Service: starting...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig
        at dataMoverServerPackage.Main.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

For whomever is curious, here is the java version output.

```
c:\>java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Here is the relevant main() function.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
    ...
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(DataMoverServerResource.class);
```

I did research and read that the big difference between Java 6,7,8 and Java 9 is modules. In particular earlier versions of Java included the Java EE JDK, whereas Java 9 includes the java.se module, not the EE. All com.sun.* classes are inaccessible in Java 9, as I read. These pieces of information may or may not be relevant. I do not know the internal makeup of the jersey.server API, just some articles talked of that.

I am using a jar in jar loader, so the jersey stuff is in the base jar.

[image: app jar contents showing jersey]

I am torn between an internal dependency issue on Jersey or the jersey jar. The loader seems happy just fails later at the `java.base/jdk.internal`, which tells me a module might be missing.

If there were an internal module, such as java.xml.bind, like I read in [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345147/android-sdk-manager-throw-exception-with-java-9), which is included in Java EE, then the exception trace would indicate that and I would know to add that module using the `--add-module` option to java, such as `--add-module java.xml.bind`, but that is not the case here, at least with that module.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437785/java-9-dependency-issues-regarding-serviceloader) to one possibly relevant article. Maybe the `java.net` is the problem, much like the `at javax.xml.bind` at the bottom of the stack trace in that question was the underlying cause. I discounted the `ext` folder answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328722/jersey-gives-runtime-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-glassfish-jersey) question, as that question pertained to 1.8, which works for me and I have jar-in-jar. I note the question here because it keeps turning up on searches. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754639/javafx-weird-classnotfoundexception-after-updating-to-java-9) was also not relevant, though similar. The list goes on.

I use Eclipse, but build using ant. The Jersey stuff libraries are in my Maven .m2 folder. I did right click on my project and select Maven > Update. That is at 2.7.

[image: maven repository showing jersey-server]

I came across this [site](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/), which talks about Java 9 migration. In the site, I read that if you add `java.se.ee`, you will have access to all Java EE modules. That recommendation failed, same output. The command that I tried was:

```
java --add-modules java.se.ee -jar ./build/bin/DataMover.jar
```

I did check SO and quite a few other sites but have turned up empty so far. Thoughts?